# DSum for cumulative sum with 2 criteria

Tags: ms-access

I am running an Access query with a DSum formula to get a cumulative sum based on 2 criteria.

Here is the base query:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 08/02/2021 | 4000 |
| 2 | 15/02/2021 | 200 |
| 2 | 25/01/2021 | 500 |

I have tried the following formula:

*DSum("[Value]","[Query]","[ID]=" & [ID] & " and [Date]<=#" & [Date] & "#")*

And here is the outcome vs the expected:

| ID | Date | Value | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 08/02/2021 | 4000 | 4000 |
| 2 | 15/02/2021 | 4200 | 4200 |
| 2 | 25/01/2021 | 4200 | 4700 |

If anyone could help me understand why i do not get the last operation, I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: Maybe because dates are shown in international format. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: Hi, I tried a couple of different formulas, still the same outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using a proper string expression for the date:

```
DSum("[Value]","[Query]","[ID]=" & [ID] & " And [Date]<=#" & Format([Date], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```

Comment: It worked! I had thought it had not worked. But I had forgotten the #!!!